# Setting Up a Wordpress Function in theme's function.php File

Tags: function, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I am trying to create the below function in my theme's function.php file and call it from my taxonomy.php file via

```
query_brands_geo('dealers', 'publish', '1', $taxtype, $geo, $brands);
```

all variables are set in taxonomy.php.

The below query works perfect if I put it directly in my taxonomy.php file.  What am I missing to make this work as a function?

As a function I get this error statement for argument repeated for 2-6:

> Warning: Missing argument 2 for query_brands_geo()

```
function query_brands_geo($posttype, $poststatus, $paidvalue, $taxtype, $geo, $brands) {
    /* Custom Query for a brand/geo combination to display dealers with a certain brand and geography */
    //Query only for brands/geography combo and paid dealers

    $wp_query = new WP_Query();

     $args = array(
       'post_type' => '$posttype',
       'post_status' => array($poststatus),
       'orderby' => 'rand', 
       'posts_per_page' => 30,
       'meta_query' => array(
           array(
               'key' => 'wpcf-paid',
               'value' => array($paidvalue),
               'compare' => 'IN',
           )
       ),
        'tax_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => $taxtype,
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $geo
                ),
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'brands',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $brands
                )

            )

        );
    $wp_query->query($args);

}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'query_brands_geo' );
```

Comment: What if you use `'post_type' => $posttype,` ?

Comment: Ah, I missed those quotes.  I made the change but still not getting the result of the query.  Any other ideas on why the query might not be executing?  Perhaps I need to move the $wp_query back to my taxonomy.php file.  Is there a way I can get the $args back?  Maybe return $args?  I am not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I tested in and it works like this : Correct your function code like this :

```
function query_brands_geo($posttype, $poststatus, $paidvalue, $taxtype, $geo, $brands) {
/* Custom Query for a brand/geo combination to display dealers with a certain brand and geography */
//Query only for brands/geography combo and paid dealers

 $args = array(
   'post_type' => '$posttype',
   'post_status' => array($poststatus),
   'orderby' => 'rand', 
   'posts_per_page' => 30,
   'meta_query' => array(
       array(
           'key' => 'wpcf-paid',
           'value' => array($paidvalue),
           'compare' => 'IN',
       )
   ),
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => $taxtype,
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $geo
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'brands',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $brands
            )

        )

    );
query_posts($args);

}
```

Then in taxonomy.php, go like this :

```
query_brands_geo('post', 'published', ..., ..., ...);
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 

the_content(); // Etc.

endwhile; // end of the loop.
```

Answer (score 0):

You say you want to use this function that you place in functions.php and have it executed in your taxonomy.php file. Right, but the code you have posted shows that you are executing it as an action (the function code is followed by : `add_action(...`). So what you have done there is that you have hooked your function to the `after_setup_theme` hook. So the function is not getting executed by the call you have (I suppose) placed in taxonomy.php, it is actually automatically executed by WP after the theme setup, when `do_action('after_setup_theme'...)` is executed by WordPress! And in this context, only one argument is passed, so you get the error message : *argument 2 is missing...*
So take out the `add_action(...)` line, keep your function in functions.php and just normally call it in taxonomy.php. It should work.

Comment: Thank you so much that solved the error message.  However I am not seeing the filter results from my query on when I view the taxonomy.php page in the browser.  Is there something I need to return from this function to make the query actually execute on the taxonomy.php page?

Answer (score 0):

You need to return something from your function, so change this at the end of the function code:

```
$wp_query->query($args);
```

with this :

```
$result = $wp_query->query($args);
wp_reset_query();
return $result;
```

And call it appropriately in taxonomy.php, knowing that the result object of the function, when called like this :

```
$myquery = query_brands_geo($arg1, $arg2, ...); // Etc.
```

Will be a query result object, so you have to loop through it, etc. (see the WordPress code elsewhere with loops).

Comment: Thank you again. I am still not getting the filtered query results.  This query works if placed in the taxonomy php file, but of course I want it to be a function.   I changed my function per your above returning $results.  In my taxonomy php file I have the following:`$myquery=query_brands_geo('dealers', 'publish', '1', $taxtype, $geo, $brands);`  Then after that I have the loop `<?php if (have_posts()) : ?><?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>`.  I even tried `<?php if (have_posts()) : ?><?php while ($myquery->have_posts()) : $myquery->the_post(); ?>` Is something else I am missing?

Comment: When I use the `<?php if (have_posts()) : ?><?php while ($myquery->have_posts()) : $myquery->the_post(); ?>`  I get this error: Fatal error: Call to a member function have_posts() on a non-object in /home3/answerun/public_html/wp-content/themes/tipztheme/taxonomy.php on line 99

Answer (score 0):

I have just tested this on a WP site and it works so it should for you too if you respect the same logic:

```
            function query_brands_geo($posttype, $poststatus) {
              $args = array(
               'post_type' => $posttype,
               'post_status' => array($poststatus) 
                );
                $result = new WP_Query($args);
                wp_reset_query();
                return $result;
            }

            $result = query_brands_geo('post', 'published');
            while ( $result->have_posts() ) : $result->the_post(); 
                the_content();
            endwhile; // end of the loop.
```